# laravel send mail to

Tags: laravel, email, message, send

Good evening everyone, I have some issues, with send mail to:
I have a code in controller, and have data taken from database with joins, this $survey variable shows gives me emails of the survey which belongs to team.
But I need some how to send an email for all emails which I gets from $survey variable. When I put $survey variable inside $message->to($survey); it shows me **Undefined variable**

my code below , how can I use it. When I put in ->to(); normal one email adress it works, but I need to send same email to all team members

```
public function startSurvey(Request $req) {

    $nameSurvey = $req->input('SurveySelectBox');
    $startDate = $req->input('surveyStartDate');
    $endDate = $req->input('surveyEndDate');

    $data = array(
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'started_at' => $startDate,
        'ended_at' => $endDate
    );

    DB::table('survey')->where('surveyId','=',$nameSurvey)->update($data);

    $survey = Survey::where('surveyId' , '=', $nameSurvey)
        ->join('team','team.teamId', '=', 'survey.teamId')
        ->join('teammembersall','teammembersall.TeamId', '=', 'team.TeamId')
        ->join('users','users.id', '=', 'teammembersall.UserId')
        ->select('users.email')
        ->get();

    Mail::raw('You have new survey to answer: http://localhost:8000/profile', function ($message) {
        $message->from('kristijanask@gmail.com', 'New Survey released');
        $message->to($survey);
    });

    return redirect('surveyDrafts');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `use ($survey)` to use the variable within the Mail anonymous function:

```
Mail::raw('...text', function ($message) use ($survey) {
    $message->from('kristijanask@gmail.com', 'New Survey released');
    $message->to($survey);
});
```

You might also need to use [`->pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) and `toArray()` on the query result, to make the result an array:

```
$survey = Survey::where('surveyId' , '=', $nameSurvey)
    // long query
    ->get()
    ->pluck('email')
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: With this correction, I'm getting error: "Illegal offset type"

Comment: Any idea which part causes the error? I didn't thoroughly go through the code. Edit: I plucked `mail`, but you're selecting `email`. Maybe that's it (I mistyped it)

Comment: I have changed it to mail, still the same. I was changed to email, because in database its named email. And I'm getting a long comment , with red noted place: public function addTo($address, $name = null)
    {
        $current = $this->getTo();
        $current[$address] = $name;
 
        return $this->setTo($current);
    }

Comment: Hmm, maybe it doesn't accept Laravel's collection as the parameter and you need to call toArray at the end: `->pluck('email')->toArray()`. I'll update my answer as well.

Comment: Works perfect now! Thank you for your help!